# 403 Forbidden Assets

Tags: assets, image, error

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. When assets are added, they upload fine but when I add them to entries or try to view them in the browser, they won't display and show a 403 Forbidden page instead. 
Help! :)

Comment: Complete shot in the dark but could it be a permissions problem where the assets dir were created by a different user/group than what the system is trying to access them under?

For example, the dir was created by "apache", but the system (craft) was created by "admin" each having different user group permissions...

Comment: Thanks @Damon! I managed to get it working, and that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This article will help you set permissions properly for Craft CMS installs:

[Hardening Craft CMS Permissions](https://nystudio107.com/blog/hardening-craft-cms-permissions)

It leverages [Craft-Scripts](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts) to do the heavy lifting.